# Select MYSQL, listar linha não presente na tabela NULL

Tags: mysql, pdo, null

Estou fazendo um hotsite com um quiz (perguntas e respostas), com mais de 3000 usuários. A dúvida está na listagem dos quizes para cada usuário, tenho duas tabelas (simplifiquei para focar na minha dúvida):

**QUIZ:** (que guarda todos os quizes criados pelo admin, o campo **total** é o total de perguntas de cada quiz)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**QUIZ_GERAL** (que é criado toda vez que um usuário inicia um quiz, campo **respondido** é quantas perguntas o usuário já respondeu nesse quiz)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando vou listar para o usuário os quizes que ele já finalizou, não tenho problemas:

```
SELECT quiz.id AS quizid, quiz.mes, quiz.ano, quiz.total, quiz_geral.respondido FROM quiz_geral 
INNER JOIN quiz ON quiz_geral.idquiz = quiz.id
WHERE (quiz_geral.idconta = :idLogado AND quiz_geral.respondido = quiz.total)
ORDER BY quiz.ano ASC, quiz.mes ASC
```

O problema está na hora de listar os quizes NÃO terminados e NÃO começados, pois tenho que listar eles em uma única consulta, ordenado pelo mês/ano, até agora fiz assim:

```
SELECT quiz.id AS quizid, quiz.mes, quiz.ano, quiz.total, quiz_geral.respondido FROM quiz_geral 
RIGHT JOIN quiz ON quiz_geral.idquiz = quiz.id
WHERE (quiz_geral.idconta = :idLogado AND quiz_geral.respondido <> quiz.total)
OR (quiz_geral.id IS NULL)
ORDER BY quiz.ano ASC, quiz.mes ASC
```

Até lista certo os quizes começados e não terminados, o problema está em listar os quizes não começados (que não estão ainda na tabela **QUIZ_GERAL**), na tabela exemplo que coloquei aqui, da forma que fiz, não seria listado para o usuário com **idconta** 100 o quiz com **id** 1, pois a linha `OR (quiz_geral.id IS NULL)` não entraria nesse caso, já que existe na tabela, mas com outro **idconta**.

Como fazer essa segunda consulta de forma correta?